# RAD: Cannot import projects from Clearcase view

Tags: clearcase, rad

I am doing my development on RAD, with Clearcase as the source control tool.

Here is what I trying to do:

1. I created new projects and added them to source control in view A, delivered view A, then make a new baseline
2. I created view B and rebase it to the latest baseline
3. I created a new workspace in RAD, and try to import projects from view B, now problem happens, no projects is shown in view B, but when I choose view A, those projects exists

Does anyone have idea? And is there any command that I can list out all files in view B so that I can make sure the problem is not about the rebase? I really don't know what to check for this problem.

This is to update on how I resolved the problem:

Thanks for VonC's clues, some of the files used by RAD was not added to source control, making the projects invisible...

1. In RAD, click Window->Preferences
2. In the popup, open the section Team->Ignored Resources
3. Search for the following patterns: ".project", ".factorypath", ".classpath". If you cannot find these patterns, that's fine, otherwise, uncheck them so that RAD would not bypass these files.
4. Run "Find Resources to Add to Source Control" to add the missing files to ClearCase

Comment: Hi Arthas, Did your files actually make it to your new workspace?

Comment: Yes. I finally made it, you can find my updates in the post

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation would be that the RAD project files (at least the `.project`) are private (that is: not versioned).

Those files would be visible in `viewA`, but not visible in `viewB`, as the latter only display what has been versionned and baselined.

Comment: Thanks for your clues. I compared the workspace on viewA and viewB and found the differences